# How to sort in mongoDb using gem 'mongo' with Ruby (Sinatra)?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sorting

**I NUMBERED THE SORTING SHOWS IN RED BOX**:

[image]

I have the following codes, but I failed to sort the data fetched from MongoDb.

**display_order** = field in DB

```
MongoConnect = Mongo::Client.new(127.0.0.1:27017, :database => 'my_db')

MongoConnect[:clients].find(:year => '2015').sort({month: 1})
```

I searched that **sort function** has ONLY 2 possible value:

**1** is Ascending

**-1** is Descending

It seems correct because I tried to put like '**asc/desc**' or '**ascending/descending**' value, and I got error as Invalid value for sort.

As you can see in the screenshot, the sorting is not properly done.
It sorts the data, by getting first all with **1**.

**BUT** I want to sort it in **ASCENDING** order.

Is it due to **STRING** data? If **YES** how can I fix it?

Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is - you've correctly identified that the sort order needs to be 1 or -1 rather than :asc or similar. What happens next?

Comment: Hi @FrederickCheung, yes seems the code is correct but the output was not. Please see the screenshot for the sorting output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your fields contain strings they will be sorted as such. If you want them to be sorted as integers then you must store them as integers.

Comment: Hi @Fred. I thinking the same idea before. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

My **mistake**, I thought before I cannot use unqouted value when creating records since I'm using **mongo-express as GUI**.

My first way when adding value to **month** field:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID(""),
    "year": "2015",
    "month": "1",
    "value": "90"
}
```

I thought, the value should **always be quoted**.

Now, my function for sorting is working. Just removing the **qoutes** as setting value to **month** field.

As shown below:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID(""),
    "year": "2015",
    "month": 1,
    "value": "90"
}
```

I hope this will help others, and don't do the same mistake I made :D